# unable to RDP to azure windows vm

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, rdp

- I was able to RDP to my win10 azure VM 2 days back just fine and all of a sudden RDP is broken.
- can see login screen on boot screen but RDP doesn't work.
- tried to redeploy to another host, reapply state but no effect used
- diagnostic tool which did not report any error and also used network
- watcher to test RDP from my IP and it showed that connectivity is not blocked.

Observations:

- It takes a lot of time to start VM which wasn't the case 2 days back
- Below image shows "host" is not assigned.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tE5W.png)

Comment: Does using the Bastion service work?

Answer (score 1):

My apologies for the delayed response.

I took a look on your image. Having "-" in the host parameter is totally fine and expecting, unless you created [a host group and etc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dedicated-hosts#groups-hosts-and-vms)
This configuration is absolutely not related to your RDP failures.

Please, review the **[standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-rdp-connection)** RDP troubleshooting steps:

After each troubleshooting step, try reconnecting to the VM:

1. Reset Remote Desktop configuration.
2. Check Network Security Group rules / Cloud Services endpoints.
3. Review VM console logs.
4. Reset the NIC for the VM.
5. Check the VM Resource Health.
6. Reset your VM password.
7. Restart your VM.
8. Redeploy your VM.

As always during the troubleshooting the first question to ask, **what error message are you getting** when you try to RDP?

Depending on it, you may follow up with the steps outlined in the Public Articles:

- [The remote session was disconnected because there are no Remote Desktop License Servers available to provide a license.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-specific-rdp-errors#rdplicense)
- [Remote Desktop can't find the computer "name".](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-specific-rdp-errors#rdpname)
- [An authentication error has occurred. The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-specific-rdp-errors#rdpauth)
- [Windows Security error: Your credentials did not work.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-specific-rdp-errors#wincred)
- [This computer can't connect to the remote computer.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-specific-rdp-errors#rdpconnect)

Hope above is helpful for anyone to start the RDP failures troubleshooting.